# How can keep API still working even mongo secondary down?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, replicaset

I'm using mongoose to connect to mongodb server.
Mongodb server is a replica set, contain a PRIMARY and a SECONDARY instance

My API cannot start if I stop SECONDARY, after SECONDARY is shutdown, I check rs.status() and see my PRIMARY change to SECONDARY.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167440/mongodb-replica-set-and-preventing-primary-from-becoming-a-secondary

Comment: @dododo Thanks but main question, how I can start API if I shutdown one of db. It is possible ?

Comment: the first answer says that you should play with either votes for a rs node or a number of arbiters.